# Omitting personal pronoun (I) in resume

Tags: word-usage, grammar

1) *Have* experience in research

2) Experience in research

Which one of above examples is correct, note that is for resume, so the from of sentence fragments is used and personal pronoun (I) is omitted.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use either one of those; I'd use either:

> Research experience

or:

> Experienced researcher

depending on whether you wanted the bullet content to apply to you (use the latter) or to your qualifications (use the former).